# Layout a second graph of the same nodes in the same way

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have a number of graphs with the same nodes.

I would like to be able to somehow save the layout that results from the spring embedded results of one graph (the first image), and have the other graphs position the nodes in the same locations (which would otherwise get you the second image).

Not sure if there is a property of the first graph that can be applied to the second. Or whether I need to create a manual set of coordinates using VertexCoordinates to apply to each.

Ideas?

[image]

[image]

The data for the two graphs is

```
{"Al-1" -> "Bru-2", "Bru-2" -> "Gra-7", "Chas-3" -> "Ned-14", 
 "Dave-4" -> "Bru-2", "Ed-5" -> "Ned-14", "Frank-6" -> "Unwin-21", 
 "Hal-8" -> "Unwin-21", "Ian-9" -> "Ned-14", "Jo-10" -> "Ron-18", 
 "Ken-11" -> "Ron-18", "Leo-12" -> "Unwin-21", "Mal-13" -> "Ned-14", 
 "Ned-14" -> "Gra-7", "Ollie-15" -> "Ned-14", "Pat-16" -> "Bru-2", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Unwin-21", "Ron-18" -> "Gra-7", "Sam-19" -> "Ned-14", 
 "Tom-20" -> "Ned-14", "Unwin-21" -> "Gra-7"}
```

and

```
{"Al-1" -> "Bru-2", "Al-1" -> "Dave-4", "Al-1" -> "Hal-8", 
 "Al-1" -> "Leo-12", "Al-1" -> "Pat-16", "Bru-2" -> "Al-1", 
 "Bru-2" -> "Ron-18", "Bru-2" -> "Unwin-21", "Chas-3" -> "Ned-14", 
 "Chas-3" -> "Sam-19", "Dave-4" -> "Al-1", "Dave-4" -> "Bru-2", 
 "Dave-4" -> "Hal-8", "Dave-4" -> "Leo-12", "Dave-4" -> "Pat-16", 
 "Dave-4" -> "Quinn-17", "Ed-5" -> "Bru-2", "Ed-5" -> "Ian-9", 
 "Ed-5" -> "Ken-11", "Ed-5" -> "Ned-14", "Ed-5" -> "Quinn-17", 
 "Ed-5" -> "Sam-19", "Ed-5" -> "Unwin-21", "Frank-6" -> "Bru-2", 
 "Frank-6" -> "Gra-7", "Frank-6" -> "Ian-9", "Frank-6" -> "Leo-12", 
 "Frank-6" -> "Quinn-17", "Frank-6" -> "Unwin-21", 
 "Hal-8" -> "Dave-4", "Jo-10" -> "Chas-3", "Jo-10" -> "Ed-5", 
 "Jo-10" -> "Hal-8", "Jo-10" -> "Ian-9", "Jo-10" -> "Leo-12", 
 "Jo-10" -> "Pat-16", "Jo-10" -> "Tom-20", "Ken-11" -> "Al-1", 
 "Ken-11" -> "Bru-2", "Ken-11" -> "Chas-3", "Ken-11" -> "Dave-4", 
 "Ken-11" -> "Ed-5", "Ken-11" -> "Hal-8", "Ken-11" -> "Ian-9", 
 "Ken-11" -> "Leo-12", "Ken-11" -> "Mal-13", "Ken-11" -> "Ollie-15", 
 "Ken-11" -> "Quinn-17", "Ken-11" -> "Ron-18", "Ken-11" -> "Sam-19", 
 "Leo-12" -> "Al-1", "Leo-12" -> "Dave-4", "Leo-12" -> "Quinn-17", 
 "Leo-12" -> "Unwin-21", "Mal-13" -> "Ed-5", "Mal-13" -> "Ken-11", 
 "Ned-14" -> "Gra-7", "Ned-14" -> "Ollie-15", "Ollie-15" -> "Al-1", 
 "Ollie-15" -> "Chas-3", "Ollie-15" -> "Ed-5", 
 "Ollie-15" -> "Frank-6", "Ollie-15" -> "Ian-9", 
 "Ollie-15" -> "Ken-11", "Ollie-15" -> "Ned-14", 
 "Ollie-15" -> "Sam-19", "Pat-16" -> "Al-1", "Pat-16" -> "Bru-2", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Al-1", "Quinn-17" -> "Bru-2", "Quinn-17" -> "Chas-3", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Dave-4", "Quinn-17" -> "Ed-5", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Frank-6", "Quinn-17" -> "Gra-7", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Hal-8", "Quinn-17" -> "Ian-9", "Quinn-17" -> "Jo-10", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Ken-11", "Quinn-17" -> "Leo-12", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Ned-14", "Quinn-17" -> "Ollie-15", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Pat-16", "Quinn-17" -> "Sam-19", 
 "Quinn-17" -> "Tom-20", "Quinn-17" -> "Unwin-21", 
 "Ron-18" -> "Bru-2", "Sam-19" -> "Al-1", "Sam-19" -> "Bru-2", 
 "Sam-19" -> "Chas-3", "Sam-19" -> "Ed-5", "Sam-19" -> "Ken-11", 
 "Sam-19" -> "Leo-12", "Sam-19" -> "Ned-14", "Sam-19" -> "Ollie-15", 
 "Sam-19" -> "Tom-20", "Tom-20" -> "Ken-11", "Tom-20" -> "Ron-18", 
 "Unwin-21" -> "Bru-2", "Unwin-21" -> "Leo-12", 
 "Unwin-21" -> "Quinn-17", "Unwin-21" -> "Ron-18"}
```

UPDATE

It would also be ideal to be able to colour-code the vertexes according to the the final column in the list below (numbered from 0 to 4).

```
{{"Al-1", 33., 9.333, 3., 4.}, {"Bru-2", 42., 19.583, 2., 
  4.}, {"Chas-3", 40., 12.75, 3., 2.}, {"Dave-4", 33., 7.5, 3., 
  4.}, {"Ed-5", 32., 3.333, 3., 2.}, {"Frank-6", 59., 28., 3., 
  1.}, {"Gra-7", 55., 30., 1., 0.}, {"Hal-8", 34., 11.333, 3., 
  1.}, {"Ian-9", 62., 5.417, 3., 2.}, {"Jo-10", 37., 9.25, 3., 
  3.}, {"Ken-11", 46., 27., 3., 3.}, {"Leo-12", 34., 8.917, 3., 
  1.}, {"Mal-13", 48., 0.25, 3., 2.}, {"Ned-14", 43., 10.417, 2., 
  2.}, {"Ollie-15", 40., 8.417, 3., 2.}, {"Pat-16", 27., 4.667, 3., 
  4.}, {"Quinn-17", 30., 12.417, 3., 1.}, {"Ron-18", 33., 9.083, 2., 
  3.}, {"Sam-19", 32., 4.833, 3., 2.}, {"Tom-20", 38., 11.667, 3., 
  2.}, {"Unwin-21", 36., 12.5, 2., 1.}}
```

I can easily make up a labelling type of table

```
{{"Al-1" -> 3.}, {"Bru-2" -> 2.}, {"Chas-3" -> 3.}, {"Dave-4" -> 
   3.}, {"Ed-5" -> 3.}, {"Frank-6" -> 3.}, {"Gra-7" -> 
   1.}, {"Hal-8" -> 3.}, {"Ian-9" -> 3.}, {"Jo-10" -> 
   3.}, {"Ken-11" -> 3.}, {"Leo-12" -> 3.}, {"Mal-13" -> 
   3.}, {"Ned-14" -> 2.}, {"Ollie-15" -> 3.}, {"Pat-16" -> 
   3.}, {"Quinn-17" -> 3.}, {"Ron-18" -> 2.}, {"Sam-19" -> 
   3.}, {"Tom-20" -> 3.}, {"Unwin-21" -> 2.}}
```

But do I map the number to a colour? I was thinking some kind of rule or assignment to VertexStyle, eg. {0->Black,1->Blue,2->Green,3->Red,4->Yellow}, but exactly how to apply it I am not sure.

Comment: By the way, welcome to Mathematica.SE! Please consider registering your account so that any upvotes you get on this question are added to those you might get on future questions and answers. That way, over time you will be able to do more on the site (post graphics, edit things, etc).

Comment: Thanks. Done. 

I've been using Mathematica for many basic things, but now I have a few projects that need more advanced analysis.  I have a lot to learn, so you will see more of me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assign your data to variables, for convenience:

```
gDat1 = {"Al-1" -> "Bru-2", "Bru-2" -> "Gra-7", ... };

gDat2 = {"Al-1" -> "Bru-2", "Al-1" -> "Dave-4", ... };
```

Find your 1st graph layout:

```
g1 = Graph[gDat1, GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"]
```

[image]

Build your 2nd graph using 1st graph vertex coordinates:

```
g2 = Graph[gDat2, AbsoluteOptions[g1, VertexCoordinates], VertexStyle -> Red];
```

[image]

Verify that there is indeed exact correspondence between vertex coordinates of 2 graphs:

```
Show[g1, g2]
```

[image]

Comment: Very much appreciated Vitaliy. That AbsoluteOPtions function will come in handy.