# How can I get precisely the subgraph corresponding to a set of edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the complete graph on 3 vertices.

[image]

Then, a method gives me a list of interesting edges, say $\{(1,2),(2,3)\}$. I want to get a subgraph of $g$ that corresponds to precisely the given edgelist. How can I do this?

If I use `Subgraph[g,e]` with `e = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3}`, I get back the original graph. This does preserve the colors, but includes an extra edge, namely $(3,1)$ that I don't want. However, `Subgraph` does have a pattern as an argument. That might do the trick, but perhaps there's an easier way.

Comment: Isn't your expected output exactly the same as your input, i.e. `Graph[Most[e]]`?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be careful with the `Subgraph` function. Here's the description of the function from the help: "The subgraph generated by the vertices $v_1$, $v_2$,... includes the vertices $v_i$ and all edges connecting them in the original graph g.' In other words, the second argument is not a graph, it is a set of vertices (to be taken from the graph specified in the first argument). It then show those vertices and all connected edges.

Perhaps the simplest way to get a picture of the subgraph (by removing edges) is to remove the edges from the graph object. In this case:

```
Graph[e, Options[g]]
```

which gives the connectivity you want.

[image]

If your graph `g` is already defined, then you can use `EdgeList[g]` to get the edges, then remove the ones you want
.

Comment: Seems like removing the unwanted edges form the definition is the most straightforward way: in this case, Graph[Most[e]] will give you the same connectivity as what you are asking for. (The picture doesn't look the same, but the graph is the same).

Comment: If your graph `g` is already defined, then you can use `EdgeList[g]` to get the edges, then remove the ones you want.

Comment: Your question answers perfectly my original question. Would you happen to know how I can preserve the EdgeStyle associated with the edges? Seems like `Options[g,{EdgeStyle}]` doesn't work because it includes an EdgeStyle for *every* edge in the original graph `g`. Anyway, since I changed the meanings of my question after you had answered, I will definitely accept your answer. I will keep working on the problem and update your question if I crack it.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it staying within `EdgeStyle`. A more straightforward way would be to define the styling via a list and to then index into that list exactly as you are indexing into the edgelist. That way the styling would stay consistent.

Comment: A new question is now [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26217/how-can-i-preserve-the-properties-of-edges-of-the-original-graph-g-in-a-subgra).

Comment: If you want to preserve the layout of the graph, check out this answer about keep node locations http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11106/2393